# Can't dynamically link to MongoDB c driver library

Tags: c, mongodb

I'm really perplexed as to what the problem could be. I put **libbson.a libbson.so libmongoc.a
libmongoc.so** into the same folder as my executable. The header files are also in the same folder.
Then I `make` it with this:

```
CFLAGS += -I. -std=c99 $(shell pkg-config --cflags json) \
          $(shell pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0) 
LDFLAGS +=  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib $(shell pkg-config --libs glib-2.0) \
            $(shell pkg-config --libs json) -lpcre -L. -Wl,-rpath,. \
            -lmongoc -lbson


all: main.o
    gcc $(LDFLAGS) -ggdb main.o -o main

main.o: main.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS)-ggdb  -c main.c
```

**Compiling works, but when I try to run it the dynamic linker complains!**
`ldd main` shows this: (why does it only complain about lbson for example and not show lmongoc at all?)

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffb2fc9000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fd0dd9bd000)
    libjson.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libjson.so.0 (0x00007fd0dd7b5000)
    libpcre.so.0 => /lib64/libpcre.so.0 (0x00007fd0dd57f000)
    libbson.so.0.4 => not found
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd0dd212000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fd0dd009000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd0ddcaf000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd0dcdec000)
```

Information about .a files is a little sparse, but as far as I was able to find out, linking should happen the same way as with .so files right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treating the .a file like an object file solved it. It should however be possible to treat it like a library file too. This still doesn't work.